# Making a CORS client-side request with Webpack - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, cors

I'm using Webpack to bundle my javascript code and use modules in the browser.

I'm trying to get the body of a URL (http://www.redbubble.com); however, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.redbubble.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is the code I am bundling and making my request to grab the body html for http://www.redbubble.com (including this in my ejs under script tag reference)

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'http://www.redbubble.com',
  withCredentials: false
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    window.console.log("callback is being called");
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    alert(body);
  } else {
    window.console.log(error);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I am also trying to use the CORS module in my **app.js** to resolve the `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` error, but it's no good.

```
app.use(cors({
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false
}));
```

Why is this error persisting? And how can it be resolved?

Comment: "I am also trying to use the CORS module in my app.js" — Your `app.js` is running on `localhost:3000`, not on `www.redbubble.com`

Comment: @Quentin can you clarify? What exactly should I do then?

Comment: Setting the headers did not fix the error

Comment: "Setting the headers did not fix the error" — How did you change them? Do you work for redbubble and have access to their servers?

Comment: So I read:  "There is nothing you can do in your client-side code that will enable CORS access to someone else's server." 

I'm trying to figure out how exactly I should do this now?

Comment: Maybe look at the "Alternatives to CORS" section of the accepted answer on the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing the OTIONS in the methods like this:

```
app.use(cors({
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "preflightContinue": false
}));
```

The explanation why you need it can be found here: [Understanding cors](http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/)
You need to make the OPTIONS method available because it is used amongst the server and the client in order to negotiate the call.

Comment: The code and the error message quoted in the question both show that it is not a preflighted request. OPTIONS isn't needed.

Comment: @Quentin What should I do then?